# Convert bitcoin transaction hash to raw hexcode

Tags: cryptography, hex, blockchain, bitcoin, pycrypto

I have a list of Bitcoin transaction hashes like this one: a4ad67ea73c88b635e003700290239e6beab7dc5c9b31f58cd34084418b7316d

I would like to convert this hash to raw format (in hexcode). For example, the blockchain API converts this transaction hash to the following (https://blockchain.info/rawtx/a4ad67ea73c88b635e003700290239e6beab7dc5c9b31f58cd34084418b7316d?format=hex):

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

One way to get the raw transaction bytes isto query the API, but this is very time consuming since my dataset is large. I am therefore wondering if there is an easier way to do this conversion. I am using Python.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The raw tx is the hexdump of the `ecdsa` signature for the BTC tx. In order to convert from a tx hash, to the raw tx, you need to look it up on chain. You can do this in Python, but it would mean having a full copy of the blockchain locally.

Comment: Hi Woodstock, thanks for your comment. I do have a full copy of the blockchain, but do not know how to look it up. Can you please help?

Comment: Updated with an answer below @akd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have a local copy of the blockchain you can use `getrawtransaction` and `decoderawtransaction` from [python-bitcoinlib](https://readthedocs.org/projects/bitcoinlib/downloads/pdf/latest/).

```
from bitcoinlib.services.bitcoind import BitcoindClient
bdc = BitcoindClient.from_config('/usr/local/src/.bitcoinlib/config/bitcoin.conf') txid = 'a4ad67ea73c88b635e003700290239e6beab7dc5c9b31f58cd34084418b7316d'
rt = bdc.getrawtransaction(txid)
print("Raw: %s" % rt)

> Raw: 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
```

Remember, in Bitcoin transaction hashes are shown little-endian rather than big-endian.

Comment: Thanks @Woodstock, I will try your solution. However, I cannot find bitcoin.conf in the bitcoinlib/config folder. Can you advice how to find it? I am using Mac OSX and have Bitcoin Cor running.

Comment: How did you install the lib? Using Pip?

Comment: Just do `pip show moduleName` to show its location, and thus the config location. If using home-brew with pip this will be something like /usr/local/blah/opt/

Comment: Hi @Woodstock, I tried your solution, but got the following error:  
                                                            
``bitcoinlib.services.authproxy.JSONRPCException: -5: No such mempool transaction. Use -txindex or provide a block hash to enable blockchain transaction queries. Use gettransaction for wallet transactions.``

Comment: Read the message... “ Use -txindex or provide a block hash to enable blockchain transaction queries.” You need to start the BTC daemon with -txindex=1 enabled to use this feature. It will take time to build the index. The answer I have provided is correct. You’re just hitting issues with implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. One more issue is that I am trying to get the hexcode for a large number of transactions, and running the client using concurrency/multithreading is not helping. Any suggestions?